# .htaccess redirect causes css nor images to load

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess to force all files to go through a index.php file and I just noticed that all my references to the css, javascript, images, stop working. I think is the htaccess that is causing this, if so, how can I solve this?

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# redirect all calls to index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical cause is that your HTML templates contain relative links to your resources.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

Will fail as soon as your pages no longer reside under `/index.html` but in `/app/index`. You now have a new virtual directory in your URL, hencewhy the CSS and images are assumed to be located under `/app/` too if you didn't specify absolute path names `/img/logo.png` everywhere.

A classic workaround is to add this in your template `<head>`:

```
<base href="/">
```

This will force browsers to prepend the `/` (in this example) to all relative resource links.